# Accessing a website on private network

Tags: url, web-applications, dns, ip, ubuntu-14.04

I developed a NodeJS web application meant to be accessed on a private wifi network.

My goal is to have users connect to my server hosted on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, on which I setted up a Wifi hotspot. 
The users connect to the wifi network with mobile devices, and then go with their browser to 
http://my.server.local.ip/

What is the easiest way to set up a DNS (or something else) so that they are able to browse to a human readable URL instead of my IP ?

Sorry if the question has been answered before, I am a beginner in network configuration and I may not search the good keywords.

Thanks for reading

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that my network provides no access to Internet. I already own a domain for this app, but for the online-version of it. My goal is to build a portable server machine which can serve the application to mobiles on bad Internet coverage areas.

Comment: Get a domain, then add a DNS record to it would be the easiest and most complete way.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my network provides no access to Internet. I already own a domain for this app, but for the online-version of it. My goal is to build a portable server machine which can serve the application to mobiles on bad Internet coverage areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which machine acts as the DNS-server for your network. Does your Server/WiFi-AP just redirect/bridge the traffic to an ethernet-port and the DHCP-requests from the mobile devices are answered by another device (router-box?) in your network? In that case, that box will also be the DNS-server the mobile devices will be querying for hostname resolution. Maybe you can configure a static IP and hostname for your Ubuntu-server in the router's web interface.

Otherwise, you can set up a DHCP and/or DNS-server on the Ubuntu-machine. A lightweight tool for this job is DNSmasq (http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html). This seems to be what you want, reading your latest comment. Configure a static IP address for the server-machine's WiFi-Interface and configure your DNS-server running on the Ubuntu-machine to map the hostname/domain of your choice to that IP. Then the mobile devices can access the website delivered by the Ubuntu machine by using that domain name.

Comment: I think dnsmasq is what I was desperately looking for. Thank's a lot.